# Unable to instantiate trait

Tags: scala

I try to define a simple trait like this:

```
scala> trait T { def p[A,B]: Map[A,B] }
defined trait T

scala> new T { def p = Map(0 -> 1) }
<console>:7: error: object creation impossible, since method p in trait T of type [A,B]Map[A,B] is not defined
       new T { def p = Map(0 -> 1) }
       ^
```

How come?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have a generic method, but the implementation of an abstract generic method must itself be generic:

```
scala> trait T { def p[A,B]: Map[A,B] }
defined trait T

scala> new T { def p[S, T] = Map[S, T]() }
res13: java.lang.Object with T = $anon$1@1f74864
```

Remember that unbounded type parameters are universally quantified. You're saying p is defined for all pairs of types without exception or constraint. Many S and T bindings are incompatible with Int, so you cannot just return a Map[Int, Int] where a Map[S, T] is required.

**Update:** Re: "So I can have non-generic implementations of generic abstract classes and traits but not of generic methods?"

You can have non-generic implementation of generic abstract classes in this sense:

```
abstract class C[A, B, C] { /* ... */ }
class D extends C[Int, String, Boolean] { /* ... */ }
```

Or like this:

```
class E extends C { /* ... */ }
```

Though that one's the same as:

```
class E extends C[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing] { /* ... */ }
```

And `Nothing` is an uninhabited type in Scala.

But you cannot implement an abstract generic method with a non-generic method

Comment: So I can have non-generic implementations of generic abstract classes and traits but not of generic methods?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to do this:

```
scala> trait T[A,B] { def p: Map[A,B] }
defined trait T

scala> new T[Int,Int] { def p = Map(0 -> 1) }
res0: java.lang.Object with T[Int,Int] = $anon$1@2f1261b1
```

Comment: Why? Can I not have a generic method in T?

Comment: Levi, that doesn't make sense.
If the method is parameterized with A,B, then the As and Bs will vary with each call:

def p[A,B] : Map[A,B] = Map(0 -> 1)

But the above method cannot possible return anything but Map[Int,Int] so if I were to call your method as:

val a = p[String,Boolean]() 

what sense does that make?

Of course you can have type parameters to your methods, but your use-case is nonsensical.